# I have problems when I try to import a new project example

Tags: android, gradle

I've just started with programming. When I try to import a new project example, I get the next error:

> Error:Failed to open zip file.
>   Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

I got Android Studio 2.3

I need your help.

Comment: Which project example are you trying to import?

Comment: this https://github.com/udacity/ud839_ViewPager_Example/tree/quiz

Comment: If you go to File -> Open... and select the build.gradle file in the root folder you should be able to run the project with no issues

Comment: I still have the same error...   Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>

Comment: Oh, I see. You should check your Gradle version maybe? Go to File -> Project Structure -> Project, and verify your Gradle version there, I am currently using version 2.14.1

Comment: I am using version 3.3

Answer (score 0):

I just delete the folder .gradle in my project´s folder.